# Como popular JComboBox com um array de strings?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma classe que herda de `JFrame` e tem um `JComboBox comboBoxPorta = new JComboBox();`.

Gostaria de popular esta combo com as portas seriais. Tenho uma função em outra classe a imprimir este procedimento.

```
 public void popularComboPorta() {
     String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
     for (String portName : portNames) {
         //System.out.println(portName);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inicio Impressao" + portName);

    }
```

Usando exemplos já existentes, tem criar uma função na classe do form retornando a `JComboBox`, mas da erro dizendo que a classe não esta resolvida.
Isto parece tão simples mas estou parado isso.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar:

```
comboBoxPorta.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(SerialPortList.getPortNames()));
```

Exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Panel extends JFrame {

    String []ports;

    public Panel(String []ports){
        initializeComponents();
        this.ports = ports;
    }

    private void initializeComponents(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox<String>();
        JButton button = new JButton("Popular Combobox");
        button.addActionListener(listener -> {
            combobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(this.ports));
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(combobox, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

Executando:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String [] ports = {"A", "B", "C"};
        new Panel(ports).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: exemplo]</kbd>